# Simplifying a geometric sum

Tags: summation

For some choice of $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n$, what would be a general formula for

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \lambda^k
$$

as a function of $\lambda$ and $n$?

Answer (score 1):

We verify easily (by induction for example) that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda^k=\left\{\begin{array}\\\lambda\;\text{if}\;n=1\\\lambda\frac{1-\lambda^n}{1-\lambda}\;\text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$

Answer (score 1):

This is known to be

$$
\frac{\lambda^{k+1} - 1}{\lambda - 1}
$$

To see why, expand out
$$
(\lambda - 1) (\lambda^k + \ldots + \lambda + 1)
$$

EDIT

Thanks for pointing out what integer the index began from. Let $\Sigma$ stand for the sum in question. The fix is easy.

Then 
$$
(\lambda - 1)(\Sigma + 1) = (\lambda^{k+1} - 1) \\
\implies \Sigma + 1 = \frac{\lambda^{k+1} - 1}{\lambda - 1} \\
\implies \Sigma = \frac{\lambda^{k+1} - 1}{\lambda - 1} - 1 \\
= \frac{\lambda^{k+1} - 1 - (\lambda - 1)}{\lambda - 1} \\
= \frac{\lambda (\lambda^k - 1)}{\lambda - 1}
$$

Comment: The first expression you wrote is not equal to the OP's series (the series starts at $k=1$)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I fixed it.

Comment: Actually, my fix was overly complicated and could be shortened by noting that $(\lambda^k + \ldots + \lambda)$ is just $\lambda \times (\lambda^{k-1} + \ldots +1)$, and then this reduces to the 'standard' solution times $\lambda$.